# Yii2-User Module vs Core AuthClient

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm rookie in Yii yramework, and interested in implementing user authentication.
I found two way to do that. One via yii2's core authclient and the second is Yii2-User module, which is not stable version.
As i know, core Auth classes gives ability to implement authentication in a good way.

What I need is **Authenticating** users via **social APIs** and **Authorizing** theme to some objectives, such as posting, viewing, commenting and etc.

**1.** So, Is there anyone give me a brief of yii2-user module and it's **benefits** over core authClient?

**2.** I think Yii2's core AuthClient classes give us all features and abilities that Yii2-User module has, Am I right?